# Open collapsed ListTile after choose row

Tags: flutter

How could I do so that on the `onTap` of the line I open another `ListTile` below?

```
return ListTile(
              title: Html(data: "<br/> <b>${team[index]['code']}</b>"),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  // call open colapsed or child listtile here
                });
              },
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to show more `ListTile` items when the user taps on one of the `ListTile` items?

If that's the case, you can use `ExpansionTile` instead.

Here is an example code:

```
ExpansionTile(
  onExpansionChanged: (res) {
    print(res ? 'Open' : 'Close');
  },
  title: Text('Dropdown'),
  children: [
    ListTile(
      title: Text('Test #1'),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
      onTap: () {
        print('Test #1');
      },
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text('Test #1'),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
      onTap: () {
        print('Test #1');
      },
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image]

P.S. You can also nest `ExpansionTile` inside another `ExpansionTile`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how you would make the selected line the focus of the list go up and the selected line be at the top of the screen?